# Scala: Problem with foldLeft with negative numbers in list

Tags: scala, filter, pattern-matching, fold

I am writing a Scala function that returns the sum of even elements in a list, minus sum of odd elements in a list. I cannot use mutables, recursion or for/while loops for my solution. The code below passes 2/3 tests, but I can't seem to figure out why it can't compute the last test correctly.

```
def sumOfEvenMinusOdd(l: List[Int]) : Int = {
    if (l.length == 0) return 0
    val evens = l.filter(_%2==0)
    val odds = l.filter(_%2==1)
    val evenSum = evens.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
    val oddSum = odds.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
    evenSum-oddSum
  }

//BEGIN TESTS
val i1 = sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(1,3,5,4,5,2,1,0)) //answer: -9
val i2 = sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(2,4,5,6,7,8,10)) //answer: 18
val i3 = sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(109, 19, 12, 1, -5, -120, -15, 30,-33,-13, 12, 19, 3, 18, 1, -1)) //answer -133
```

My code is outputting this:

```
defined function sumOfEvenMinusOdd
i1: Int = -9
i2: Int = 18
i3: Int = -200
```

I am extremely confused why these negative numbers are tripping up the rest of my code. I saw a post explaining the order of operations with foldLeft foldRight, but even changing to foldRight still yields i3: Int = -200. Is there a detail I'm missing? Any guidance / help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so the problem is that `-3 % 2 == -1` which means that your two filter statements will actually both just throw out all negative odd numbers. 

Also i think you can do this with a single foldLeft/foldRight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't `foldLeft` or `foldRight`, the problem is the way you filter out odd values:

```
val odds = l.filter(_ % 2 == 1)
```

Should be:

```
val odds = l.filter(_ % 2 != 0)
```

The predicate `_ % 2 == 1` will only yield true for positive elements. For example, the expression `-15 % 2` is equal to `-1`, and not `1`.

As as side note, we can also make this a bit more efficient:

```
def sumOfEvenMinusOdd(l: List[Int]): Int = {
  val (evenSum, oddSum) = l.foldLeft((0, 0)) {
    case ((even, odd), element) =>
      if (element % 2 == 0) (even + element, odd) else (even, odd + element)
  }
  evenSum - oddSum
}
```

Or even better by accumulating the difference only:

```
def sumOfEvenMinusOdd(l: List[Int]): Int = {
  l.foldLeft(0) {
    case (diff, element) =>
      diff + element * (if (element % 2 == 0) 1 else -1)
  }
}
```

Comment: you are an actual life saver, you have no idea how long i was stumped on that! thank you!

Comment: Even more efficient to accumulate the difference rather than doing that at the end. You also don't need the `isEmpty` test, it will work OK even with an empty list.

Comment: @Tim Added an additional example with a running diff :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the filter condition that you apply on list to find odd numbers.
the odd condition that you doesn't work for negative odd number because mod 2 return -1 for this kind of number.

```
number % 2 == 0 if number is even
number % 2 != 0 if number is odd
```

so if you change the filter conditions all works as expected.

Another suggestion: 
Why you want use foldleft function for a simple sum operation when you can use directly the sum functions?

```
  test("Test sum Of even minus odd") {
    def sumOfEvenMinusOdd(l: List[Int]) : Int = {
      val evensSum = l.filter(_%2 == 0).sum
      val oddsSum = l.filter(_%2 != 0).sum
      evensSum-oddsSum
    }

    assert(sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List.empty[Int]) == 0)
    assert(sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(1,3,5,4,5,2,1,0)) == -9) //answer: -9
    assert(sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(2,4,5,6,7,8,10)) == 18) //answer: 18
    assert(sumOfEvenMinusOdd(List(109, 19, 12, 1, -5, -120, -15, 30,-33,-13, 12, 19, 3, 18, 1, -1)) == -133)
  }
```

With this solution your function is more clear and you can remove the if on the funciton

Comment: The `foldLeft` solution is more efficient, but if you want to build each list then use one call to `partition` rather than two calls to `filter`.

Comment: thank you! i appreciate the feedback, this is maybe my 20th hour coding with Scala so i'm not quite onto the tips and tricks yet!

Comment: @MeganByers You have a wonderful journey ahead of you, but with a few nasty surprises on the way :)

Comment: @Tim you are right. But I never mentioned performance optimization on my code, only a more clear solution based on the starting code.